# delay add/remove class on mouseenter/hover

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to delay adding and removing classes to elements when the user hovers over an element:

```
$('#thumbs div').mouseenter(function() {            
    $('#thumbs div').removeClass('hovered');
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
});
```

Is there a way to do this? I would like a delay of around 0.3 seconds for example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $("#thumbs div").mouseenter(function() {   
      $(this).removeClass('hovered');
      setTimeout("addClassCustom", 300);
 });

 function addClassCustom() {
      $("#thumbs div").addClass('hovered');
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like this

```
$("#thumbs div").on('mouseenter', function() {            
    var el = $(this);    
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#thumbs div').removeClass('hovered');
        el.addClass('hovered');
    }, 300);
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
    var el = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        el.removeClass('hovered');
    }, 300);
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/W4erG/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#thumbs div").mouseenter(function() {            
    var self = $(this);    

    self.removeClass('hovered');

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        self.addClass('hovered');
    }, 300);
});
```

Comment: jQuery's delay only works on the FX queue, i.e. animations, not other methods.

Comment: Well, I wasn't sure about that, that the reason I've also added the 2nd option. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could queue it:

```
$("#thumbs div").mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).delay(300).queue(function(next){
    $('#thumbs div').removeClass('hovered');
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
    next();
  });
});
```

You'll probably want to cancel it/clear the queue if the mouse leaves with something like http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/.